# Как сравнить URL страницы и ссылки, и при совпадение удалить?

Tags: jquery

Как сравнить URL страницы и ссылки, и при совпадение удалить?

Comment: Кого удалить-то? Принятый ответ радует, но формулировка вопроса совершенно невнятная

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете использовать такой вариант:

```js
let url = location.href;
url = 'yandex.ru' // Удалить эту строчка, сделанно для имитации ссылки.
$('.url').each(function(){//Переберём дивы
  let thisURL = $(this).data('url'); // Получим атрибут data-url
  if(thisURL==url) $(this).addClass('remove'); // если адресс страницы совпадает с data-url - вешаем класс remove. Это для визуализации.
  // Чтобы удалить блок, используйте ↓
  // $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.remove {opacity: .5; color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="url" data-url="google.com">google.com</div>
<div class="url" data-url="yandex.ru">yandex.ru</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можешь получить URL текущей страницы.

```
var page=window.location.href;
```

А ссылку по id элемента получить можно

После чего сравнить и сделать то, что пожелаешь